# Playwright seems unable to play songs on spotify web

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, playwright

I've accessed the spotify website (open.spotify.com) through playwright fine, but when i manually navigate around trying to play a song and click play nothing happens. I've tried both Firefox and Chromium and it seems that they meet the version requirement for spotify. So im not sure what is going wrong.

```
const baseURL = 'https://open.spotify.com/'
const playwright = require('playwright')
const browserType = ['firefox']

function sleep(ms) {
    Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, ms);
}

async function login(email, password, proxy) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch({headless:false})
    /*const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch({
        headless: false,
        proxy: {
            server: proxy,
        },
    });*/
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2F');
    let emailField = page.getByPlaceholder('Email address or username')
    let passwordField = page.getByPlaceholder('Password')
    await emailField.type(email, {delay: 5})
    await passwordField.type(password, {delay: 5})
    let loginButton = page.getByTestId('login-button')
    await loginButton.click()
}
```

Comment: i dont see how the code is really relevant here but: https://hatebin.com/zboipvcirq

Comment: Thanks for the code. I see the login, but I don't see any attempts to click a song. Also, since it's behind a login, this limits who can help to those with a spotify account. Hopefully someone will show up.

Comment: Yes, I was just testing playing songs manually as I was in headless mode, I haven't bothered adding functionality for it if it doesn't work manually.